# Scale svg image to fit parent as css background

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to have an svg image to be scaled as follows:

[image: sketch]

The right arrow (painted in red) should always scale to the height of the blue box, which can have dynamic height.

I have tried implementing it using an svg image:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
   <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 50 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
      <polygon points="0,0 50,50 0,100" style="fill:white" />
    </svg>
```

I tried different versions of preserveAspectRatio and viewBox.

My css implementation is like

```
#before-main section header.section-header .header-arrow {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    width:4.1%;
    background:url("../img/headlineArrow_bg.svg") no-repeat right center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

HTML looks like

```
<header class="section-header">
    <div class="header-arrow">
    </div>
</header>
```

Is there a way to implement this using the svg image as css background?

Edit: Width of The arrow should always stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your red arrow stretch to match the height, try `preserveAspectRatio="none"`.